# Soap from Node.js

Tags: node.js, soap

How to generate soap request in node.js for the below xml

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cred="http://credential.transport.v1.api.cmpublish.clickability.com" xmlns:tran="http://transport.v1.api.cmpublish.clickability.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <cred:credentials username="" password="" customerID=""/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tran:getSubscriberByEmail>
         <email></email>
         <domainID></domainID>
      </tran:getSubscriberByEmail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a WSDL to point things at, I've found [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) to be straight forward.

From their readme:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```